# How to move an image on a canvas to a specific location using ImageMagick?

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I am using ImageMagick to place an image on particular location on a white background canvas, can someone help me with it?

Here is what i tried so far, this would resize my image to correct resolution and put on a right size canvas.

```
Convert image.jpg -resize 1025x1537 -background white  -extent 1920x1536
```

Now, I need to move it 40 pixles to the right , 20 to bottom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading the documentation for the geometry argument, it seems like one can use:

```
... -extent 1920x1536+40+20
```

If you want to define the offset from another origin, then you can use `-gravity type`.

https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-processing.php#geometry
https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#gravity

Comment: Thanks a ton ! it worked like a magic, appreciate your time here, saved a lot on my side